# Passing query parameters to LiveData/Viewmodel in Android app

Tags: java, android, android-mvvm

Since I'm new to programming Android apps I followed a tutorial on how to use the Android Architecture Components and Firebase for implementing the MVVM (using LiveData, ViewModel, etc.).

The tutorial I followed can be found here:

- [Part 1](https://evanamargain.com/android/android-livedata-and-viewmodel-in-java-tutorial/)
- [Part 2](https://evanamargain.com/android/firebase-firestore-for-android-architecture-components/)
- [Part 3](https://evanamargain.com/android/firestore-with-android-architecture-components-integration/)

I'm now left with what I think is a decent implementation of the MVVM, but I can not wrap my head around how I am supposed to pass query parameters to it. Right now I need to hardcode the ID of the document I want to retrieve:

```
public class AlarmDAO {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    public AlarmLiveData getFirestoreLiveData() {
        DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection(Collection.ALARMS.name).document("5RxJNuNyhDJlz49wpBkw");

        return new AlarmLiveData(documentReference);
    }

}
```

That then gets called by a class extending `ViewModel`.

```
public class AlarmViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private AlarmDAO DAO = new AlarmDAO();
    private AlarmLiveData liveData = null;

    public LiveData<Alarm> getAlarmLiveData() {
        liveData = DAO.getFirestoreLiveData();
        return liveData;
    }

    public LiveData<Alarm> getAlarm() {
        return liveData.alarm;
    }

}
```

And then I observe that data in my activity:

```
model.getAlarmLiveData().observe(this, Observable -> {});
model.getAlarm().observe(this, alarm -> {
   if (alarm != null) {
      alarmTextView.setText(alarm.getTest());
   else {
      Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for data");
   }
});
```

My problem is that I do not see a way of querying for a specific alarm. For instance `model.getAlarm("someId")`. I am under the impression that it should be done in the DAO and/or the ViewModel, but I can't figure out how. Another thing I do not understand is why I need to observe both `model.getAlarmLiveData()` and `model.getAlarm()` in my activity, as using only one does not work. The answer to both of those questions is most likely very simple, but thus far I haven't been able to figure it out.

For completeness: the `Alarm` class is nothing besides a getter and setter for two strings, and the `AlarmLiveData` class is below.

```
public class AlarmLiveData extends LiveData<Alarm> implements EventListener<DocumentSnapshot> {

    private static final String TAG = AlarmLiveData.class.getSimpleName();

    private Alarm alarmTemp = new Alarm();
    private DocumentReference documentReference;
    private ListenerRegistration listenerRegistration = () -> {};

    public MutableLiveData<Alarm> alarm = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public AlarmLiveData(DocumentReference documentReference) {
        this.documentReference = documentReference;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        listenerRegistration = documentReference.addSnapshotListener(this);
        super.onActive();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        listenerRegistration.remove();
        super.onInactive();
    }


    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            alarmTemp = new Alarm();
            alarmTemp.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
            alarmTemp.setTest(documentSnapshot.get("test").toString());
            alarm.setValue(alarmTemp);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading, I'm looking forward to the answer(s)!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to use both `model.getAlarmLiveData()` and `model.getAlarm()` looks to be that your AlarmLiveData class extends LiveData but sets a value for the contained MutableLiveData member variable instead of setting its own class value.

Inside your AlarmLiveData class:

```
// Comment out/Remove your 'public MutableLiveData<alarm> alarm' member variable from the top.
// You're going to want to set the value of the AlarmLiveData class itself instead.

// ...

// Then inside of your onEvent callback
@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
        alarmTemp = new Alarm();
        alarmTemp.setId(documentSnapshot.getId());
        alarmTemp.setTest(documentSnapshot.get("test").toString());
        
        // Set the value for the AlarmLiveData class directly
        setValue(alarmTemp);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "ERROR");
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why you're creating a DAO class and I would most likely move that code directly into the AlarmViewModel class.
But, here is how you can alter your current DAO class if you don't want to remove it:

```
// Pass in the document id you want to create a document reference for
public AlarmLiveData getFirestoreLiveData(String documentId) {
    DocumentReference documentReference = firebaseFirestore.collection(Collection.ALARMS.name).document(documentId);

    return new AlarmLiveData(documentReference);
}
```

Your AlarmViewModel class would look something like this:

```
public class AlarmViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private AlarmDAO DAO = new AlarmDAO();
    private AlarmLiveData liveData = null;

    // Make sure to take in the document id so you can create the corresponding LiveData
    public LiveData<Alarm> getAlarmLiveData(String documentId) {
        // Only create a new LiveData instance if the current one is null.
        // This is helpful if you intend to use this as a Shared ViewModel.
        if(liveData == null){
            liveData = DAO.getFirestoreLiveData(documentId);
        }
        
        return liveData;
    }
}
```

Finally, in your Activity:

```
// Pass in the document id and observe the ViewModel
model.getAlarmLiveData("MY_DOCUMENT_ID").observe(this, alarm -> {
   if (alarm != null) {
      alarmTextView.setText(alarm.getTest());
   }else{
      Log.d(TAG, "Waiting for data");
   }
});
```